# Squid: disable X-Forwarded-For, but only for specific ACLs

Tags: squid, x-forwarded-for

I know, that I can turn off X-Forwarded-For header in Squid completley by using directive "forwarded_for off" or "forwarded_for delete" globally. I would like to be able to disable that header only for specific ACLs, so I can disable this header only for given URLs and have it enabled for others. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ACL based on an external file to store URLs (easier to manage in my opinion) :

```
acl NoXForwardedFor dstdomain "/etc/squid/NoXForwardedFor.txt"
```

The content of `/etc/squid/NoXForwardedFor.txt` would be something like this :

```
.serverfault.com
.superuser.com
.stackoverflow.com
```

Then remove `X-Forwarded-From` from the header for the given ACL :

```
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny NoXForwardedFor
```

Note : You can use the `dst` directive instead of the `dstdomain` directive.
   But it requires URL host's IP address, so make sure the target domain has
   fixed ip address(es).

Maybe some useful links for deeper understanding :

- http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_access/
- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl
- http://linuxgazette.net/161/prestia.html

Comment: Thank you very much, but from what I know - maybe I am wrong - this is **not** the same thing, as removing the X-Forwarded-For header completly. This just stops parsing of the value of that header to track the original location. My use case is different - I want to get rid of the header completly (remove it from the request that goes from squid to the website), but only for specific domains.

Comment: @dotz I have edited my answer. Give it a try !

Comment: Thanks a million, the second approach works. Please edit your reply so it includes only the second approach (as the first one simply does not do what I wanted) and I'll accept it as an answer. THANKS!

Comment: @dotz You are welcome, glad it works ! Ok, edited.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and a great contribution to serverfault.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the same and the correct syntax is

```
acl NoXForwardedFor dst "/usr/pbi/squid-amd64/etc/squid/NoXForwardedFor.txt"

request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny NoXForwardedFor
```

where `NoXForwardedFor.txt` contains domain names.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything compared to the accepted answer.